# MySQL "NOT IN" / "LEFT JOIN" giving an error

Tags: php, mysql, phpbb

I wanted to write additional query to phpbb3 [karma mod](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=559069) which checks that a user can't give karma to same person before he hasn't given karma to 3 other persons. But i'm receiving error in my SQL syntax...

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519272/mysql-not-in-query) and [this](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) link and query i've written looks as follow

```
SELECT * 
FROM phpbb_karma AS out 
WHERE out.poster_id = 134
AND out.poster_id
NOT IN 
(SELECT k.karma_id, k.user_id, k.poster_id
FROM phpbb_karma AS k
WHERE user_id = 108
ORDER BY k.karma_id DESC LIMIT 3)
```

So my inner query gets the 3 last persons (`poster_id`) whom he (`user_id`) gave karma. This query alone works but together with my outer query it gives me error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'out WHERE out.poster_id = 134 AND out.poster_id NOT IN (SELECT
>   k.karma_id, k.u' at line 2

In my outer query i write that the person who will be receiving karma is `134` and that he must not be present in my inner query result.

What could be wrong with that query? Is the error really in second row?

I wrote the same query with LEFT JOIN, but it gives me same syntax error

```
SELECT *
FROM phpbb_karma AS out
LEFT JOIN phpbb_karma AS in
ON in.poster_id = out.poster_id
WHERE in.poster_id = 134 AND in.poster_id IS NULL
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'out LEFT JOIN phpbb_karma AS in ON in.poster_id = out.poster_id
>   WHERE in.poster_' at line 2

MySQL version is `MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 304625 $` but i don't think that the problem is in version, because the LEFT JOIN doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different alias, because `out` is a reserved keyword: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: thank you. i accepted first reply

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using reserved words as the alias you cannot use `NOT IN` or `IN` with a sub-select that returns more than one column.

You are basically telling MySQL to compare a single value from `poster_id` to three different values. Now which one should it take?

Once you get the problem with the alias sorted out, you need to remove two columns from the sub-select.

Based on your naming schema I assume you actually want

```
NOT IN (SELECT k.karma_id FROM phpbb_karma ....)
```

instead.

Comment: uhh, didnt edit in 5 minutes, so i write as reply that it works now when i omit LIMIT 3 in my inner query otherwise it says ˇThis version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT &amp; IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'ˇ

Answer (score 0):

`out` is a keyword in MySQL.  You can fix this either by naming the alias something else or putting backticks around `out`.

Comment: the same goes for the alias `in`

Answer (score 0):

Just put back-ticks  around `out` and `in`. looks like they are reserved keywords in mysql