# Select all field where field value not in array

Tags: php, mysql

I have this array in a variable

```
$regions = |north|south|west|
```

and a database field "Region" that contains a single value e.g. north

I need a select statement that will select all the fields where the value of "Region" is not any of the values listed in the array. e.g. north, south, west.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where is `$regions` coming from?  Because that's not an array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519272/mysql-not-in-query

Comment: I have multiple checkboxes in the form. If the user selects north and south and west, I need to display all records that do not have north south or west in the region field

Comment: Rocket, your comment helped me solve the issue. I was passing the data as a string and not as an array.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in SQL with `WHERE field NOT IN('value1', 'value2', ...)`. [Basic string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) are probably sufficient to get your array in this format.

Comment: values are in an array and they will change depending on user selection

Answer (score 2):

```
$regions = "north|west|south";
$regionsArray = explode('|', $regions);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($regionsArray); $i++) {
    $regionsArray[$i] = "'" . $regionsArray[$i] . "'";
}

$query = "SELECT *
FROM ...
WHERE Region NOT IN (" . implode(",", $regionsArray) . ")";
```

This assumes that your `$regions` variable is a string like described, and not an array.

If it was an array before then there is quite likely no need to convert it to a string though (the above code converts it back into an array).

Comment: I tried this but this is what I get:
Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in

Comment: @sheredia: Is `$regions` an array or a string that contains e.g. "north|west|south"?

Comment: @sheredia: I edited my answer to show you a more detailed code example.

Comment: The code produces an SQL statement that will select all entries from your table except the ones where `Region` contains any of the values. Where is the problem?

Comment: this is the error that I get
**Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in...**

Comment: That most likely means that you are not getting any results from the database. This can be due to an invalid query or if there are just no results in the table that match. Print out the generated query and then issue it 'manually', like e.g. through phpmyadmin.

Comment: I tried this sql statement applied to the WordPress wp_users table and user_email field, with a comma delimited string of five email addresses as the list. It doesn't work, returning all email addresses. I just found out it doesn't work because the list (or if you use `implode()`) doesn't wrap each list item with a ' (opening and closing apostrophe). So, implode(",",$str) produces "user1@gmail.com,user2@mydomain.com,user3@mydomain.com". That fails the sql. The list has to be constructed like this: `WHERE user_email NOT IN ('user1@gmail.com','user2@mydomain.com','user3@mydomain.com')";`

Answer (score 1):

maybe you forget about mysql_real_escape_string() ?

```
function db_escape($value)
{
    return '"'.mysql_real_escape_string($value).'"';
}

$regions = array('north','west','south');

$query = "SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `Region` NOT IN (" . implode(",", array_map('db_escape',$regions)) . ")";
```