# How can I get the opposite of WHERE id IN (...)?

Tags: php, mysql

The following query looks the table `ids` and return the `id` if for example 204720966837 is found.

My question is how can I do the opposite? I want to display the ids of those id that are not found.

```
SELECT id FROM ids WHERE id IN  ('204720966837', '163700377960', '24583115900', '1081617368').
```

For now I have *204720966837* saved in `ids` and this is what it prints. My goal is to print *163700377960, 24583115900, 1081617368*

```
while($assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $assoc['id'];   
}
```

I have tried NOT IN but I get a zero return.

Comment: NOT IN sounds right to me. Are you sure that zero return isn't the correct answer for your data? Really sure?

Comment: @JohnFx How can it be right when it does not return me 163700377960, 24583115900, 1081617368? I have only 204720966837 saved in.

Comment: Break the problem into 2 steps - what happens if you run the `NOT IN` query directly against your db (MySQL WorkBench/phpMyAdmin)? I can't see any reason `NOT IN` wouldn't work if the data's there...

Comment: @Basic I run it through phpMyAdmin. When I use `IN` it returns me the one it is saved. When I use `NOT IN` I get 0 rows.

Comment: Select count(*) from ids;  then select count(*) from ids where ID in ('your list') then select count(*) from ides where ID not in ('your list')  if you Not in + in is <> count then you have a serious problem. as your db doesn't understand set logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (id int);

INSERT INTO temp_table(id) VALUES('204720966837'), ('163700377960'), ('24583115900'), ('1081617368');

SELECT id FROM temp_table WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM ids)

DROP TABLE temp_table;
```

Comment: He's not looking for the rows in the database that aren't in his list of IDs - he's looking for the IDs in his list that aren't in the database.

Answer (score 3):

My wild guess is that you want:

```
SELECT id
FROM
  ( SELECT 204720966837 AS id
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 163700377960
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 24583115900
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 1081617368 
  ) AS tmp
WHERE id NOT IN
      ( SELECT id FROM ids )
```

Comment: @Basic: "gah" stands for [awesome](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2011-12-30/), I suppose :)

Comment: I'd go as far as functional and readable, however, it lacks a little elegance :)

Comment: @Basic: Unfortunately MySQL does not have the elegant [Table Value Constructors](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/table-value-constructors-in-sql-server-2008/)

Comment: @ypercube couldn't agree more - I cheat further and use the Entity Framework now - I never even touch SQL during development :)

Comment: Another - though similar - way: `SELECT tmp.id FROM ids RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 1 AS id UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) AS tmp ON tmp.id=ids.id WHERE ids.id IS NULL` I still wonder why there doesn't seem to be a shorter way to write a result set, without all these `UNION`...

Comment: @StockOverflaw: There is, it's called Table Value Constructor. AFAIK only Postgres and lately SQL-Server support that.

Comment: @ypercube ah right I missed the linked article you posted, thanks for the (repeated) info ;)

Answer (score 2):

`NOT IN` only works if you have a set returned.

try

`SELECT id FROM ids WHERE id NOT IN  (SELECT '204720966837', '163700377960', '24583115900', '1081617368')`

See [MySQL "NOT IN" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519272/mysql-not-in-query) for a comprehensive discussion on this topic.

Comment: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: A list of Ids is treated as a set - The OP's problem in the linked Q is that he's simply referring to `table2.principal` without a query which includes `table2`

Comment: Ok I'm not 100% on how mysql handles subqueries as sets, thanks.

Comment: You can use a subquery that returns several rows with a single column.  Selecting the literal numbers like that returns one row with several columns.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier to do the comparison in php.

```
$id_list = array('204720966837', '163700377960', '24583115900', '1081617368');

$result = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM ids WHERE id IN  (' . implode(',', $id_list) . ')');
$found = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $found[] = $result['id'];
}
$diff = array_diff($id_list, $found);
```

`$diff` will contain the IDs you were searching for, but didn't find.

Comment: That is probably the best way to go.. because MySQL isn't made for this kind of operation, where you have only some of the data you're working with in the database and the other at the client.

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
SELECT id FROM ids 
WHERE id != '204720966837' 
AND id != '163700377960'
AND id !='24583115900' 
AND id !='1081617368'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that

```
 WHERE IN ()
```

does not work either.

Give it a try and that should lead you to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Not IN** always work with sub-query, may be your **Not IN** syntex is wrong, correct it and try again.