# mysql not in rewrite query issue

Tags: mysql

I have a query with `NOT IN`. I've heard MySQL doesn't support `NOT IN`, but I can't figure how to rewrite it.

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM quests
  WHERE id NOT IN ('" .$quest_completed. "') 
  AND location=" .$location_id. "
  AND (follows=0 OR follows IN ('" .$quest_completed. "')) 
  ORDER BY title
```

eg:

```
SELECT * FROM quests 
WHERE id NOT IN (6,21) AND 
  location=8 AND 
  (follows=0 OR follows IN (6,21))
ORDER BY title
```

Row id 6 is being returned in that when I specified `WHERE id NOT IN 6`

Comment: MySQL does support `NOT IN`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Oh, maybe its my query then. It's returning rows that I dont want it to.

Comment: I hope those variables have been sanitised.  You really ought to use prepared statements as a matter of course.  Don't know what I'm talking about?  Read about [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: They're `mysql_real_escape_string`d

Comment: @user1022585: Good to hear (although prepared statements are safer still); nevertheless I'm making the habit of putting up a warning along those lines with every question where I see variables embedded in SQL, for the benefit of anyone else who might come to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, because of your use of apostrophes around the `$quest_completed` variable, the query that's actually being executed is likely to be `NOT IN ('6,21')`, rather than `NOT IN (6,21)` (which I think is what you want?).

The difference is that the first version returns records where `id` is not equal to the string `'6,21'`, whereas the second version returns records where `id` is neither the number `6` nor the number `21`.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL [supports `NOT IN` just fine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in). A restriction only applies to certain cases, like the one here: [MySQL "NOT IN" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519272/mysql-not-in-query)

Answer (score 0):

NOT IN can also be interpreted as logical NOT (some condition) such as

```
NOT ID in ( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' )
```

SO, if you are having issues as written, just try swapping ...