# MySQL - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1241

While working on a system I'm creating, I attempted to use the following query in my project:

```sql
SELECT
topics.id,
topics.name,
topics.post_count,
topics.view_count,
COUNT( posts.solved_post ) AS solved_post,
(SELECT users.username AS posted_by,
    users.id AS posted_by_id
    FROM users
    WHERE users.id = posts.posted_by)
FROM topics
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON posts.topic_id = topics.id
WHERE topics.cat_id = :cat
GROUP BY topics.id
```

":cat" is bound by my PHP code as I'm using PDO. 2 is a valid value for ":cat".

That query though gives me an error: "#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

What stumps me is that I would think that this query would work no problem. Selecting columns, then selecting two more from another table, and continuing on from there. I just can't figure out what the problem is.

Is there a simple fix to this, or another way to write my query?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Your subquery is selecting two columns, while you are using it to project one column (as part of the outer `SELECT` clause).  You can only select one column from such a query in this context.

Consider joining to the `users` table instead; this will give you more flexibility when selecting what columns you want from `users`.

```
SELECT
topics.id,
topics.name,
topics.post_count,
topics.view_count,
COUNT( posts.solved_post ) AS solved_post,
users.username AS posted_by,
users.id AS posted_by_id

FROM topics

LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON posts.topic_id = topics.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.id = posts.posted_by

WHERE topics.cat_id = :cat
GROUP BY topics.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll fix my query, and mark you as the answer, but just for input, do you think there's a "better" way to write my query than what I'm using now (but also disregarding the error in it)?

Comment: Ah. Thank you for the edit on your original post. I will be sure to mark you as the answer when StackOverflow lets me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, the `COUNT()` is throwing things off a bit; the query I've given will probably give an error due to the aggregation.  You may need to move that aggregation into a subquery, depending on the goals of your query (which are not clear to me at the moment).

Answer (score 34):

In my case, the problem was that I sorrounded my columns selection with parenthesis by mistake:

```
SELECT (p.Column1, p.Column2, p.Column3) FROM Table1 p WHERE p.Column1 = 1;
```

And has to be:

```
SELECT p.Column1, p.Column2, p.Column3 FROM Table1 p WHERE p.Column1 = 1;
```

Sounds silly, but it was causing this error and it took some time to figure it out.

Comment: I can't believe this is what my problem was, I thought brackets were legal there

Comment: Yes, this was my problem as well :) Thank you

Comment: Yes, same problem here. SQL and parenthesis and single quote marks around fields can be confusing.

Answer (score 24):

This error can also occur if you accidentally use commas instead of `AND` in the `ON` clause of a `JOIN`:

```
JOIN joined_table ON (joined_table.column = table.column, joined_table.column2 = table.column2)
                                                        ^
                                             should be AND, not a comma
```

Comment: That really saved me a lot of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

This error can also occur if you accidentally use `=` instead of `IN` in the `WHERE` clause:

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
WHERE product_id = (1,2,3);
```

Comment: Or LIKE instead of IN as i did and couldnt find why this error happens. ty for pointer.

Comment: It can also happen if you put brackets around the fields in the SELECT clause, e.g. SELECT (Field1, Field2) FROM Table

Answer (score 7):

```sql
COUNT( posts.solved_post ) AS solved_post,
(SELECT users.username AS posted_by,
    users.id AS posted_by_id
    FROM users
    WHERE users.id = posts.posted_by)
```

Well, you can’t get multiple columns from one subquery like that. Luckily, the second column is already `posts.posted_by`! So:

```sql
SELECT
topics.id,
topics.name,
topics.post_count,
topics.view_count,
posts.posted_by
COUNT( posts.solved_post ) AS solved_post,
(SELECT users.username AS posted_by_username
    FROM users
    WHERE users.id = posts.posted_by)
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this error while executing a MySQL script in an Intellij console, because of adding brackets in the wrong place:

WRONG:

```
SELECT user.id
FROM user
WHERE id IN (:ids); # Do not put brackets around list argument
```

RIGHT:

```
SELECT user.id
FROM user
WHERE id IN :ids; # No brackets is correct
```

Comment: this does not match with the first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551177/hql-unexpected-ast-node-vector

Comment: @rubydio, that question references HQL and Hibernate, whereas my answer is referring to MySQL in an Intellij console

Comment: @janac-meena thanks, i knew it, but when is already written i couldn't see the error

Answer (score 1):

This error can also occur if you accidentally miss `if` function name.

for example:

```
set v_filter_value = 100;

select
    f_id,
    f_sale_value
from
    t_seller
where
    f_id = 5
    and (v_filter_value <> 0, f_sale_value = v_filter_value, true);
```

Got this problem when I missed putting **if** in the `if` function!

Answer (score 0):

Another place this error can happen in is assigning a value that has a comma outside of a string.  For example:

```
SET totalvalue = (IFNULL(i.subtotal,0) + IFNULL(i.tax,0),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT users.username AS posted_by,
users.id AS posted_by_id
FROM users
WHERE users.id = posts.posted_by)
```

Here you using sub-query but this sub-query must return only one column.
Separate it otherwise it will shows error.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue in making a company database.
this is the code

```
SELECT FNAME,DNO FROM EMP 
 WHERE SALARY IN (SELECT MAX(SALARY), DNO
FROM EMP GROUP BY DNO);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error message using Dapper with MySQL. Example code below:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM Table
WHERE ColA IN (@listOfColumns);
```

The issue with the above code is Dapper will automatically add the brackets for
the @listOfColumns parameter substitution meaning the brackets in the snippet above will double wrap the list of columns causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I wrote in this way before:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT pr.id"
    + " FROM biz_project pr"
    + " LEFT JOIN sys_user u ON pr.create_user_id = u.id"
    + " LEFT JOIN sys_department de ON pr.department_id = de.id"
    + " WHERE :roleUsers IS NULL OR pr.create_user_id IN (:roleUsers)"
    + " AND :roleDepts IS NULL OR pr.department_id IN (:roleDepts)", 
nativeQuery = true)
List<Long> test(@Param("userIdList") List<Long> userIdList,
    @Param("deptIdList") List<Long> deptIdList);
```

It has the same error, **SQL Error: 1241, SQLState: 21000 Operand should contain 1 column(s).**

But I'll remove these two parts:':**roleUsers IS NULL OR** ' and '**:roleDepts IS NULL OR**', It can run normally and return the result I want. But I don't know why.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35477669)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).