# HQL unexpected AST node: {vector}

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, hql

I'm trying to write an HQL query to grab a list of users that belong to a particular organisation, or any franchisee from a list of franchisees, however hibernate isn't able to parse it. I can't figure out why. Here is the HQL:

```
from User u where 
(u.parentOrganisation = :topLevelOrganisation or u.parentOrganisation in :franchisees) 
and u.parentOrganisation.deleted = false 
and u.active = true
```

This is the error that hibernate spits out:

```
unexpected AST node: {vector} [from com.myapp.User u where (u.parentOrganisation = :topLevelOrganisation or u.parentOrganisation in :franchisees0_, :franchisees
1_, :franchisees2_) and u.parentOrganisation.deleted = false and u.active = true]. Stacktrace follows:
Message: unexpected AST node: {vector} [from com.myapp.User u where (u.parentOrganisation = :topLevelOrganisation or u.parentOrganisation in :franchisees0_, :fr
anchisees1_, :franchisees2_) and u.parentOrganisation.deleted = false and u.active = true]
```

If I take out the `or u.parentOrganisation in :franchisees` bit, so my query looks like this:

```
from User u where 
(u.parentOrganisation = :topLevelOrganisation) 
and u.parentOrganisation.deleted = false 
and u.active = true
```

Then it works fine. What's wrong with my syntax? Why is hibernate complaining about that extra clause?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Oh, it turns out that I needed to enclose `:franchisees` in parentheses:

```
from User u where 
(u.parentOrganisation = :topLevelOrganisation or u.parentOrganisation in (:franchisees)) 
and u.parentOrganisation.deleted = false 
and u.active = true
```

Answer (score 18):

The reason why does this happen is because when data in array is put in the list without parentheses, query syntax for searching database from the list will be wrong.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
List<Integer> userIdList = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Query without parentheses: `from User u where u.id in :list`

will look like this when data is inserted `from User u where u.id in 0, 1, 2, 3` - **WRONG SYNTAX**.

Query with parentheses: `from User u where u.id in (:list)`

will look like this when data is inserted `from User u where u.id in (0, 1, 2, 3)` - **CORRECT SYNTAX**.

Answer (score 2):

We can split condition "OR" in HQL to 2 statements.

It works fine.

```
from User u where 
(u.parentOrganisation = :topLevelOrganisation and u.parentOrganisation.deleted = false 
and u.active = true ) 
or (u.parentOrganisation in (:franchisees) and u.parentOrganisation.deleted = false 
and u.active = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have missed some parentheses,

Before Fixing :

```
" WHERE ( :status IS NULL OR ( :status IS NOT NULL AND c.caseStatus IN :status ) )"
```

After Fixing :

```
" WHERE ( (:status) IS NULL OR ( (:status) IS NOT NULL AND c.caseStatus IN (:status) ) )"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error cause I was trying to check if a query parameter supposed to be a list was null (`IS NULL`), like this:

```sql
:listParameter IS NULL or p.value IN :listParameter
```

What worked for me was to change the `IS NULL` check to the part of the code where I set the parameters, by passing a flag parameter. This flag parameter indicates whether `:listParameter` is null (or empty) or not.

In the previous example, when I create the query I would include the flag parameter (see `listParameterIsNull`):

```java
Query query = em.createQuery("Queries.nameOfTheQuery")
  .setParameter("listParameterIsNull", listParameter == null || listParameter.isEmpty())
  .setParameter("listParameter", listParameter);
```

The part of the query would look like the following:

```sql
:listParameterIsNull = TRUE OR p.value IN :listParameter
```

Hope it helps.