# JPA QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: {vector} For In condition

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to use `IN` operation with `@Query` annotation with `JPA`. I am getting below error :-

```
    antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected AST node: {vector}
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2112)

    org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
    unexpected AST node: {vector}
 [ [select o FROM Stock o where (:productlist_0_, :productlist_1_, :productlist_2_, :productlist_3_ is null or o.productsid IN (:productlist_0_, :productlist_1_, :productlist_2_, :productlist_3_) )
```

My Java code is below :-

```
@Query("SELECT o FROM Stock o  where (:productlist is null or o.productsid IN (:productlist) ) ")
List<Stockdiary> getAllStock(Pageable pageable, @Param("productlist") List<Products> productlist)
```

**this works fine when i have only single item** in `productlist`. but when i have multiple item in `productlist` is query comes out as below and error :-

```
select o FROM Stock o where (:productlist_0_, :productlist_1_, :productlist_2_, :productlist_3_ is null or o.productsid IN (:productlist_0_, :productlist_1_, :productlist_2_, :productlist_3_
```

I have look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551177/hql-unexpected-ast-node-vector) but this workaround is not working for me. 
i tried passing `:productlist` with and without parentheses.

Comment: seems like your JPA provider is incapable of handling ":param IS NULL" when the parameter is a Collection, or maybe its the combination of that with the "OR". So raise it as a bug on the provider.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue like you and the solution is quite easy. After work around I found that next variant is working fine:

```
@Query("select c from Cruise c where" +
        " (:categoryId is null or c.category.id = :categoryId)" +
        " and ((:portsIds) is null or c.port.id in (:portsIds))")
List<Cruise> findByRequestQuery(@Param("portsIds") List<Long> portsIds,
                                @Param("categoryId") Long categoryId);
```

As mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24551530/6629515 you should add parentheses to collection parameter, for me it worked if add parentheses to each collection parameter mentions:

```
(:portsIds)
```

And the result SQL query where part looks like:

```
where (? is null or cruise0_.category_id=?) and ((? , ? , ?) is null or cruise0_.port_id in (? , ? , ?))
```

For **Operand should contains 1 column** issue

Please read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51958547/1522490

In short: use `coalesce(:portsIds, null) is null`

Comment: but if I use MySQL I receive an error SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s). How to fix this?

Comment: @CatH please, provide sample of your code, I will try. I showed example for Postgresql, possible some difference here.

Comment: doesn't work for db2 either. `(? , ? , ?) is null` is invalid syntax

Comment: Regarding the `java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)`.
See @popgeh's comment below ☟

Comment: @Oleksandr H: I added solution above

Answer (score 0):

Since I could not commment on @Alex Efimov 's Answer, so I just write the answer base on @Alex Efimov 's

For @Cat H 's issue( SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s))

You could use this way(add a boolean variable to ignore query when empty collection ):
base on @Alex Efimov 's code:

```
boolean ignoreQueryPortsIds = CollectionUtils.isEmpty(portsIds);
@Query("select c from Cruise c where" +
        " (:categoryId is null or c.category.id = :categoryId)" +
        " and (:ignoreQueryPortsIds is true or c.port.id in :portsIds)")
List<Cruise> findByRequestQuery(@Param("portsIds") List<Long> portsIds,
                                @Param("categoryId") Long categoryId,
                        @Param("ignoreQueryPortsIds ") boolean ignoreQueryPortsIds );
```

note: You hava to add `is true` after `:ignoreQueryPortsIds` otherwise jpa couldn't parse your HQL

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problems, i fixed it, to reverse the `o.productsid IN (:productlist) OR :productlist is null` condition

```
@Query("SELECT o FROM Stock o  where (o.productsid IN (:productlist) OR :productlist is null ) ")

List<Stockdiary> getAllStock(Pageable pageable, @Param("productlist") List<Products> productlist)
```

Comment: :productlist is null this will make issue, if we use list of integers

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround i used another variable for null verification, because the parentheses doesn't work on all DBs. For example:

```
    @Query("SELECT o FROM Stock o  where (:hayProductos is null or o.productsid IN (:productlist) ) ")
List<Stockdiary> getAllStock(Pageable pageable, @Param("productlist") List<Products> productlist, @Param("hayProductos") Boolean hayProductos)
```

Comment: It's boolean. You could have sent a true/false there instead of null