# Checking for NULL on a Collection in JPQL queries?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am writing a JPQL query which queries based on a **Categories** collection. My categories can be null and hence I am checking using :categories=NULL.

```
@Query("Select v from Vendor v join v.org vorg join v.categories cats WHERE vorg.email =:email AND (cats in :categories or :categories = NULL)")
Set<Vendor> filterVendors(@Param("emailId") String emailId, @Param("categories") Set<Category> categories);
```

The above works fine when categories is NULL. However, when categories is more than one value I get the error

> java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

And the hibernate relevant trace is

> category6_.category_id in (
>                   ? , ?
>               ) 
>               or (
>                   ? , ?
>               ) is null
>           )

How does one check for null on a collection in JPQL ? I think solving for that should resolve this error. Any help appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: 1- what's vorg.email vorg is not an alias.
2- :email and @param define with name "emailId"

Comment: There was a small typo. Corrected it now, hope is clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I was stuck doing something quite similar. Basically you want to check to see if either

1. the collection you are passing in is empty: then don't include it in the query
2. the collection you are passing in is populated: then do include it in the query

The problem with this is there is no good way to handle this part:

```
:categories = NULL
```

This is because when translated to SQL it is going to look something like this (when 2 items are in the collection):

```
@p0, @p1 = NULL
```

You cannot wrap it in parenthesis either, because this is not valid in SQL:

```
(@p0, @p1) = NULL
```

I tried to use coalesce to reduce the values down to NULL, but I couldn't get that to work either.

Basically from what I can tell there isn't anything in JPQL that lets you run some kind of function of a collection (hashset, etc) to see if it is populated or not. If anyone knows of one please let us know.

Finally I resorted to a hack, in the calling code I check the collection to see if it is populated. If it is not I simple pass in one more parameter ... an empty string.

```
String catString = "";
if (categoryList != null && !categoryList.isEmpty()) catString = "HasCats";
```

Then in the JPQL do this:

```
WHERE (:catsString = '' or cats IN (:categories)) "
```

Not the best solution in the world but it is functional.

Comment: True, thanks for the effort in answering this almost a year later. 1 year wiser, I think what you have proposed is the only way - i use something similar or use a native query where the list of params is long.

Comment: To make it a bit cleaner, you can use apache utils or something to do list's null and isEmpty check in one go. Like this CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(categoryList) in your if condition. isNotEmpty method in apace utils will check for both null and empty conditions.

Comment: Did the same with a boolean, as of today it looks like the cleanest way to do it

Answer (score 42):

I was able to got it like this:

```
coalesce(:myIdCollection, null) is null or id in (:myIdCollection)
```

Comment: Thanks alot. You saved my day. working like a charm.

Comment: Of all the suggestions I read, this is the only one that worked that I tried.  Thank you!

Comment: You even don't need the hard coded `null` value in the `coalesce` function : `coalesce(:myIdCollection) is null or id in (:myIdCollection)` should do the job.

Comment: its worked at my dynamic jpa query

Comment: This will pollute your query cache of hibernate and db side

Answer (score 5):

If anyone using PostgreSQL encounters this problem, it can easily be fixed by adding parentheses:

```
(cats in :categories or (:categories) IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select v from Vendor v join v.categories cats WHERE vorg.email =:email AND (cats in :categories or cats IS EMPTY)
```

You can use the `IS [NOT] EMPTY` operator to test for empty collections. JPA doesn't necessarily bring back a NULL collection. Think about it, DB returns an empty collection.

Oh, I fixed your query (though I didn't test it).

Comment: I am testing the above out and getting a some SQL syntax errors when the collection is sent empty. I am curious, why are you testing cats is EMPTY ? Shouldn't we check the param categories for empty ??

Comment: Because `cats` is already declared and is assigned to `v.categories`.

Comment: Sorry, tried a lot with your suggestion, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

With **spring-data** you can use the **SpEL** on @Query definitions.

for example:

> where (:#{#categoryIds == null || #categoryIds.isEmpty()} = true OR s.id in (:categoryIds))

the *where conditions* generated in several cases are:

1. empty categoryIds

> where (?=1 or 1=0)

2. null categoryIds

> where (?=1 or s3_0.SHOP_CATEGORY_ID in(?))

3. two items in categoryIds

> where (?=1 or s3_0.SHOP_CATEGORY_ID in(?,?))

4. one item in categoryIds

> where (?=1 or s3_0.SHOP_CATEGORY_ID in(?))