# JPQL query with input parameter collection containing null

Tags: jpa, jpql, jpa-2.2

I need to compare a nullable entity property via IN expression within the following JPQL query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "query",
        query = "SELECT e FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.status IN :statuses")
```

Now, I like the shown *collection-valued input parameter* `statuses` to optionally contain `null` as an element:

```
final List<MyEntity> actual = entityManager.createNamedQuery("query", MyEntity.class)
            .setParameter("statuses", Arrays.asList(null, 1L))
            .getResultList();
```

However with Hibernate/Derby an actual result list only contains entities with status `1L` but not `null`.

I have not found anything in the JPA 2.2 specification about this case. Did I miss something or is this vendor-specific?

---

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45164322/checking-for-null-on-a-collection-in-jpql-queries) only solve part of my problem. In their proposed solutions, the `null` comparison is hard-baked into the query and cannot be controlled via the collection-valued parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking for NULL on a Collection in JPQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45164322/checking-for-null-on-a-collection-in-jpql-queries)

Comment: @Yann39 Thank you, I also spotted this question. However, the answers only solve part of my problem. In their proposed solutions, the null comparison is hard-baked into the query and cannot be controlled via the collection-valued parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a Java programmer, where `null = null` yields true it might come as a surprise that in SQL (and JPQL) `null = null` is itself `null` which is "falsy". As a result, `null in (null)` yields null as well.

Instead you need to treat `null` seperately with a `IS NULL` check: `e.status IS NULL OR e.status IN :statuses`.

This is described in 4.11 Null Values of the JPA Specification:

> - Comparison or arithmetic operations with a NULL value always yield an unknown value.
> - Two NULL values are not considered to be equal, the comparison yields an unknown value.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I indeed had a different expectation of the ORM world here, however JPQL cannot modify the semantics of SQL. For my specific case, this means that I need to introduce two corresponding JPQL queries (one with `... IS NULL OR ...` and a second without) and decide on the Java side which one to call, right?

Comment: Yes, I am afraid so!