# #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s): why?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want use a subquery in a main query like following:

```
SELECT distinct(cnt.crid),cu.companyName,m.*,cnt.*,m.submitDate as mSubmitDate 
from tbl_mahmoleh m,tbl_customer cu,tbl_cntreserve cnt 
where m.cuID=cu.cuID and m.mBLID=cnt.mBLID and m.cuID='12' 
      and (cnt.crID IN (SELECT DISTINCT(crID) FROM tbl_paymentcnt)) 
      and (cnt.crID IN (SELECT pc.crID, SUM( amount ) AS PaySum 
                        FROM tbl_paymentcnt pc GROUP BY pc.crID HAVING PaySum < '2000'))
ORDER BY inputDateD
```

but i faced by this error

> Blockquote  #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: the last `ORDER BY` should be of the main SELECT, however I don't see any column named `inputDateD` in the select list?

Comment: Because `IN` expects a single list (ie. column) of values. Two makes no sense. Move your `SUM(amount)` to the `WHERE` instead of the `HAVING`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Operand should contain 1 column(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046838/mysql-operand-should-contain-1-columns)

Comment: inputDateD is a field in tbl_mahmoleh,

Answer (score 0):

i got it, the IN clause can't work with more than one field, i changed my Query to the following and my Problem was solved.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(cnt.crid),cu.companyName,m.*,cnt.*,m.submitDate AS mSubmitDate 
FROM tbl_mahmoleh m,tbl_customer cu,tbl_cntreserve cnt 
WHERE m.cuID=cu.cuID AND m.mBLID = cnt.mBLID AND m.cuID = '12' 
AND (cnt.crID IN (SELECT DISTINCT(crID) FROM tbl_paymentcnt)) 
AND (cnt.crID IN (SELECT pc.crID FROM tbl_paymentcnt pc GROUP BY pc.crID HAVING SUM(amount) < '2500')) 
ORDER BY inputDateD
```