# Operand should contain 1 column(s) I'm getting this error while executing delete query

Tags: mysql

this is my sql query

```
delete FROM 
SubMaster_test1 
where SubMasterId in (select * 
from SubMaster_test1 where AgentId 
not in (select distinct
introducer from SubMaster_test1 
where introducer is not null))
```

i'm getting following error

[Err] 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Operand should contain 1 column(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046838/mysql-operand-should-contain-1-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should wright only "id" on "*"

```
delete FROM 
    SubMaster_test1 
    where SubMasterId in (select SubMasterId
    from SubMaster_test1 where AgentId 
    not in (select distinct
    introducer from SubMaster_test1 
    where introducer is not null))
```

Comment: [Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'SubMaster_test1' for update in FROM clause... getting this error

Comment: I know it.make a temp table  with only one column with id and insert this SubMasterId into it then use this table to delete data

Comment: insert into temp select SubMasterId
    from SubMaster_test1 where AgentId 
    not in (select distinct
    introducer from SubMaster_test1 
    where introducer is not null)

Comment: ok i have created the tem table and inserted the data... what next?

Comment: delete FROM 
    SubMaster_test1 
    where SubMasterId in (select id from temp)

Comment: have you insert SubMasterId id only ? let me know if it's works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132894/discussion-between-krishn-patel-and-anjali-jibhakate).