# Query specific columns from database table to json

Tags: php, sql, json

I'm trying to get specific columns from a database table rather than selecting the whole table and put them to json format. There's no need for irrelevant columns. This is what i have so far.

```
$sql = "SELECT (col1,col2,col3) FROM table1";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($emparray);

    mysqli_close($connection);
```

This code returns with an error: `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with the query. You are selecting 3 columns but putting them in brackets `()` would project them as single column. Try -

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM table1
```

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046838/mysql-operand-should-contain-1-columns) for details.

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify column name when access query result.

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

$sql = "SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM table1";

$emparray = array();
$index = 0;
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[$index][] = $row['col1'];
    $emparray[$index][] = $row['col2'];
    $emparray[$index][] = $row['col3'];

    $index++;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);

mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: storing values in same index would overwrite previous value. Also the error is with the query, rest is fine.

Comment: @SougataBose I didn't notice it. fixed