# Mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)'). What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I'm creating a web crawler that is capturing data from a website and then inserting it into my database. I'm using scrapy and mysql.
I created the following code:

- pipelines.py:

  ```
  class MySQLStorePipeline(object):
   def __init__(self):
   self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host ='localhost', user ='root', passwd ='', db ='imoveis', charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
   self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

   def process_item(self, item, spider):    
     try:
      self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO imovel (Titulo, Tipo_Negocio, Preco, Localizacao, Tipo_Imovel, Condicao, Numero_Divisoes, Numero_Quartos, Numero_Casas_Banho, Certificado_Energetico, Ano_Construcao, Area_Util, Area_Bruta, Piso)  
                  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", 
                 (item['Titulo'], 
                  item['Tipo_Negocio'],
                  item['Preco'],
                  item['Localizacao'],
                  item['Tipo_Imovel'],
                  item['Condicao'],
                  item['Numero_Divisoes'],
                  item['Numero_Quartos'],
                  item['Numero_Casas_Banho'],
                  item['Certificado_Energetico'],
                  item['Ano_Construcao'],
                  item['Area_Util'],
                  item['Area_Bruta'],
                  item['Piso']))            
      self.conn.commit()

  except MySQLdb.Error as e:
      print('Error %d: %s' % (e.args[0], e.args[1]))
      sys.exit(1)

  return item
  ```
- settings.py:

  ```
  BOT_NAME = 'novo'

  SPIDER_MODULES = ['novo.spiders']
  NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'novo.spiders'

  FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'

  ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'novo.pipelines.MySQLStorePipeline' : 300
  }

  ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
  ```
- crawler.py:

  ```
  class SapoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "imoveis"
   allowed_domains = ["maisconsultores.pt"]
   start_urls = ["https://www.maisconsultores.pt/properties?page=%d&s=eedce" % i for i in range(23)]

   def parse(self,response):
     subpage_links = []

     for i in response.css('div.item.col-sm-4'):
      youritem = {
      'Titulo':i.css('div[class=image] h3::text').extract(),
      'Tipo_Negocio':i.css('div.price::text').re('[^\t\n\r\a]+'),
      }

      subpage_link = i.css('div[class=image] a::attr(href)').extract_first()
      full_url = response.urljoin(subpage_link)
      yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_subpage, meta={'item':youritem})

  def parse_subpage(self,response):
      youritem = response.meta.get('item')
      youritem['Tipo_Imovel'] = response.xpath('//ul[@class="amenities"]//li[1]/text()').extract()
      youritem['Condicao'] = response.xpath('//ul[@class="amenities"]//li[2]/text()').extract()
      yield youritem
  ```

The error that appears when I run scrapy is this:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

I really dont know or cant see what I am missing here. I would really appreciate if u guys could help me out.

Comment: @Uueerdo Triple quotes simply allows you to wrap a string over multiple lines.

Comment: I don't see how you could be getting that error from the code you posted. The error happens when you use a subquery as an expression, but there are no subqueries in your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046838/mysql-operand-should-contain-1-columns for an example.

Comment: @Barmar But I did not use any subquery, I simply wanted to insert the data I removed from the site through the crawler and insert it into my database (mysql) through the use of scrapy ... I did not see anything in the link that you sent me to help me :(

Comment: Where are you calling `process_item()`? Also, the indentation of `pipelines.py` is all messed up, please fix it.

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from `process_item()`? The format of the error message you're getting is not the same as what it writes in the `except` block.

Comment: It prints `Error <number>: <message>`, but you're getting `<exception type>: (<number>, <message>)`

Comment: @Barmar I never said that the error came from the process_item () ... I do not know where it comes from ... just when I run the crawler it appears that error and I can not understand why ...

Comment: @Barmar The problem probably comes from connecting to the database because it is something that appears before such an error appears.

Comment: Where didyou define the pipeline? I don't see any custom_setting in SapoSpider

Comment: @mirhossein I did not realize what you meant. Can you explain better?

Comment: @Joana That error can't come from connecting to the DB. It's complaining about a query. You should try to print a backtrace rather than just exiting the program, so you can see where it's coming from.

Comment: @Barmar I tried to rephrase the whole code and now give me this error that I posted in this link: "  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51062223/python-sqlalchemy-exc-operationalerror-unprintable-operationalerror-object". Can you help me?

Comment: @Joana You must define desired pipelines in custom_settings variable of SapoSpider, but there isn't such variable

Comment: @mirhossein Sorry, but I can not understand what you mean. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Joana here https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider at ITEM_PIPELINES section

Comment: @Joana the problem is that your values are in list format not string, the `extract` return a list no a string, to make sure just replace the item with literals and see the result