# Python: Sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: <unprintable OperationalError object>

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, web-crawler, pipeline

I made the following code that I will present below to create a web crawler (elaborated in scrapy) and I want to put this data in a database, the one being mysql. For this I used the pipeline file and made the following configurations:

- pipeline.py:

  ```
  class ScrapySpiderPipeline(object):
     def __init__(self):

       engine = db_connect()
       create_table(engine)
       self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

       session = self.Session()
       quotedb = QuoteDB()
       quotedb.Titulo = item["Titulo"]
       quotedb.Tipo_Negocio = item["Tipo_Negocio"]
       quotedb.Preco = item["Preco"]
       quotedb.Tipo_Imovel = item["Tipo_Imovel"]

    try:
       session.add(quotedb)
       session.commit()
    except:
       session.rollback()
       raise
    finally:
       session.close()

    return item
  ```
- models.py:

  ```
  from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

  DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()

  def db_connect():
  return create_engine(get_project_settings().get("CONNECTION_STRING"))

  def create_table(engine):
     DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine)

  class QuoteDB(DeclarativeBase):
     __tablename__ = "imovel_table"

     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     Titulo = Column('Titulo', VARCHAR(200))
     Tipo_Negocio = Column('Tipo_Negocio', String(100))
     Preco = Column('Preco', Text())
     Tipo_Imovel = Column('Tipo_Imovel', Text())


  print(QuoteDB.__table__)
  ```
- items.py:

  ```
  class QuoteItem(scrapy.Item):
    Titulo = scrapy.Field()
    Tipo_Negocio = scrapy.Field()
    Preco = scrapy.Field()
    Tipo_Imovel = scrapy.Field()
  ```
- setting.py:

  ```
  ITEM_PIPELINES = {
     'novo.pipelines.ScrapySpiderPipeline' : 300,
  }

  CONNECTION_STRING = "{drivername}://{user}:{passwd}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}?charset=utf8".format(
     drivername="mysql",
     user="root",
     passwd="",
     host="localhost",
     port="3306",
     db_name="projeto",
  )
  ```
- crawler.py:

  ```
  class SapoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "imoveis"
    allowed_domains = ["maisconsultores.pt"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.maisconsultores.pt/properties?page=%d&s=eedce" % i for i in range(23)]

  def parse(self,response):
     subpage_links = []

     for i in response.css('div.item.col-sm-4'):
         youritem = {
         'Titulo':i.css('div[class=image] h3::text').extract(),
         'Tipo_Negocio':i.css('div.price::text').re('[^\t\n\r\a]+'),
         'Preco':i.css('div.price span::text').extract(),
         }

      subpage_link = i.css('div[class=image] a::attr(href)').extract_first()
      full_url = response.urljoin(subpage_link)
      yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_subpage, meta={'item':youritem})

  def parse_subpage(self,response):
      youritem = response.meta.get('item')
      youritem['Tipo_Imovel'] = response.xpath('//ul[@class="amenities"]//li[1]/text()').extract()
      yield youritem
  ```

Can someone tell me where the error is? I'm in it for a long time and I can not find it. Any idea ? I will appreciate it if someone can help me!

Backtrace:

```
2018-06-27 17:17:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.maisconsultores.pt/1651/apartamento-t2-em-linda-a-velha> (referer: https://www.maisconsultores.pt/properties?page=18&s=eedce)
2018-06-27 17:17:04 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'Titulo': ['Apartamento T2 em Linda-a-Velha '], 'Tipo_Negocio': ['                                            Venda', '                                            ', '                                        '], 'Preco': ['240 000€', 'Novo Preço!'], 'Localizacao': [' Algés (Algés)'], 'Tipo_Imovel': [' Apartamento'], 'Condicao': [' Usado'], 'Numero_Divisoes': [' 3'], 'Numero_Quartos': [' 2'], 'Numero_Casas_Banho': [' 1'], 'Certificado_Energetico': ' Avaliação em Curso', 'Ano_Construcao': ' 1980', 'Area_Util': '                                                ', 'Area_Bruta': '                                                    ', 'Piso': ['                                                                                                            2º andar', '                                                                                                    ']}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 508, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 277, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Desktop\outra_tentativa\novo\novo\pipelines.py", line 111, in process_item
    session.commit()
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 943, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 467, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 447, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2254, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2380, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2344, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 391, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 556, in execute
    uow
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 181, in save_obj
    mapper, table, insert)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 866, in _emit_insert_statements
    execute(statement, params)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 948, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 269, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1060, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1200, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1413, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 186, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 508, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\joani\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 277, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: <unprintable OperationalError object>
```

Comment: The error message implies you're using SQLAlchemy. Where is that in your code? All the web-scraping stuff is probably irrelevant.

Comment: @Barmar I am using SQLAlchemy in the models.py configuration file

Comment: Post the full backtrace. It should report the line on which the error occurred.

Comment: @Barmar I just published what you asked me ... I hope it helps you so that you can give me some indication of how to solve the error