# How to resolve operand should contain 1 column(s) for inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm new MySQL.
When I was executing the following query I'm getting operand should contain 1 column(s) error.

```
select a.status, a.order_number, a.net_order_amt, a.retailer_id, a.order_date
from (select status, order_number, net_order_amt, retailer_id, 
        (order_date/1000,'%Y-%m-%d') as order_date 
      from Order
      where FROM_UNIXTIME(order_date/1000,'%Y-%m-%d') between '2019-08-31' and '2019-08-31'
     ) as a 
INNER JOIN Retailer AS r on a.retailer_id = r.retailer_id;
```

I'm a novice programmer in MySql and I'm unable to solve the error. Can someone help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Operand should contain 1 column(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046838/mysql-operand-should-contain-1-columns)

Comment: `(order_date/1000,'%Y-%m-%d')`  - what are you trying to do here. You forgot to use the function in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the `from_unixtime` funtion in the select that causes this

```
select a.status, a.order_number, a.net_order_amt, a.retailer_id, a.order_date
from (select status, order_number, net_order_amt, retailer_id, 
        FROM_UNIXTIME(order_date/1000,'%Y-%m-%d') as order_date 
      from Order
      where FROM_UNIXTIME(order_date/1000,'%Y-%m-%d') between '2019-08-31' and '2019-08-31'
     ) as a 
INNER JOIN Retailer AS r on a.retailer_id = r.retailer_id;
```

Use the function that will solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
     ..... (order_date/1000,'%Y-%m-%d') as 
    order_date.....
```

This part of ypur query is causing that error add a function name to it like `to_date (order_date/1000,'%Y-%m-%d')` or as i see in your where clause `FROM_UNIXTIME(order_date/1000,'%Y-%m-%d')`