# 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)' error when inserting two tables into one in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I want to insert two different tables into one as per the below illustration:
[image: The tables I want to insert]

I've tried several ways like:

```
INSERT INTO com_short 
    (category_id, media_folder_id, gallery_folder_id, status, important, 
    bgPositioning, published_at, published_by, created_at, modified_at,title, 
    slug, body, featured_image_file_id) 

SELECT (SELECT com_post.id, category_id, media_folder_id, gallery_folder_id,    
               status, important, bgPositioning, published_at, published_by, 
               com_post.created_at, com_post.modified_at 
        FROM com_post 
            INNER JOIN com_post_translation ON com_post.id = com_post_translation.post_id 
        WHERE com_post_translation.post_id = com_post.id
        ),

        (SELECT title, slug, body,featured_image_file_id 
        FROM com_post_translation 
        WHERE com_post.id = com_post_translation.post_id
        );
```

But it shows an error as follows:

[image: The error]

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to SO, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046838/mysql-operand-should-contain-1-columns

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: Hi @indofraiser I have seen only now your suggested link. If I have seen it before I would not write my answer.... Now that is already there I will leave it because I believe it has some extra info OP could use... If you do not agree I will delete it.. .Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**Reason of the error:** you can not select more than one column in the subquery:

```
SELECT (SELECT com_post.id, category_id, media_folder_id, gallery_folder_id,    
               status, important, bgPositioning, published_at, published_by, 
               com_post.created_at, com_post.modified_at 
        FROM com_post 
            INNER JOIN com_post_translation ON com_post.id = com_post_translation.post_id 
        WHERE com_post_translation.post_id = com_post.id
        ),

        (SELECT title, slug, body,featured_image_file_id 
        FROM com_post_translation 
        WHERE com_post.id = com_post_translation.post_id
        );
```

**Simple explanation** :

This will produce error:

```
select (select '1', '2');
```

This will not:

```
select (select '1');
```

[Check the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f88b91cdb276c2e661f1caef31c101f)

What would be the **way to do it withot errors**:

```
INSERT INTO com_short (category_id --1
                       , media_folder_id --2
                       , gallery_folder_id --3
                       , status --4
                       , important --5
                       , bgPositioning --6
                       , published_at --7
                       , published_by --8
                       , created_at --9
                       , modified_at --10
                       , title --11
                       , slug --12
                       , body --13
                       , featured_image_file_id) --14 
SELECT cpt.category_id --1
       , cpt.media_folder_id --2
       , cpt.gallery_folder_id --3
       , cpt.status --4
       , cpt.important --5
       , cpt.bgPositioning --6
       , cpt.published_at --7
       , cpt.published_by --8
       , com_post.created_at --9
       , com_post.modified_at --10
       , cpt.title --11
       , cpt.slug --12
       , cpt.body --13
       , cpt.featured_image_file_id --14
FROM com_post 
INNER JOIN com_post_translation cpt ON com_post.id = cpt .post_id
```

**Note**: This is just an example, I can not know for sure from your question what do you want to do....

**Additional info**:

- cpt is alias for the table com_post_translation (It makes your code "lighter" and easyer to read).
- When you join two tables with ON keyword there is no need to repeat that condition in the where clause.

Comment: Hi @John was this answer of any help to you ?