# Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s) when delete duplicate

Tags: duplicates, mysql-workbench, sql-delete, delete-operator, mysql-error-1241

delete from dupp
where empno in (select empno,count(*) from dupp
group by empno
having count(*)>1)

Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)
what can i do  to slove this ??/

i want to delete duplicate and please to help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - Operand should contain 1 column(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046838/mysql-operand-should-contain-1-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is stemming from the subquery whose select contains 2 things, the `empno` and the count.  You don't even need to be selecting the count, so remove it and the query should work:

```sql
DELETE
FROM dupp
WHERE empno IN (
    SELECT empno
    FROM (
        SELECT empno FROM dupp GROUP BY empno HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) t
);
```

Comment: i tried also  that also error and the error is Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'dupp' for update in FROM clause

Comment: I have corrected that problem.  Apologies, as my code was untested.

Comment: sir,how to delete duplicate  in mysql  using row_number can you write a query create table dupps
(id int,
empno int,
salary int,
location varchar(20));
insert into dupps values
(1,101,1000,'ch'),
(2,102,1200,'mj'),
(3,103,1300,'jk'),
(4,101,1200,'dk'),
(5,104,1008,'vl'),
(6,102,1200,'mj'),
(7,105,1022,'ch'); i tired but error comes

Comment: I suggest that you open a new question.