# MySQL/PHP/HTML How to insert children in hierarchical dropdown form menu?

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu, optgroup

I have the following variables that fetch values from my database. These variables are storing Parent values of a hierarchical list (formats) and children values of the same hierarchical list:

```
$getSolos = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM wp_terms p 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy t ON p.term_id = t.term_id
        WHERE t.taxonomy = 'format'
        AND t.parent = 0
        AND t.term_id NOT IN (SELECT parent FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'format' AND parent > 0)
        ORDER BY t.parent
        "));

$getParents = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM wp_terms p 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy t ON p.term_id = t.term_id
        WHERE t.taxonomy = 'format'
        AND t.parent = 0
        AND t.term_id IN (SELECT parent FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'format' AND parent > 0)
        "));
```

Although the above isn't necessarily important, the following is as my database looks like this:

```
term_id name          slug                   term_id1    parent
1         Entry Form    entry-form           1           0
2         Facebook      facebook             2           0
3         Entry Form    entry-form-facebook  3           2
4         Twitter       twitter              4           0
5         Page          page-facebook        5           2
```

So logically, my OBJECT ARRAYS contain:

```
$getParents->parent = 2 // contains only IDs of parent formats
$getSolos->term_id = 1,5 // contains only IDs of formats that have no children
```

The idea is to populate a dropdown form menu with these formats, with parent formats being optgroups containing their children. SO far I've achieved the following:

```
<form>
    Format: <select name="format">
        <option value="empty"></option>
            <?php 
                foreach ($getSolos as $solo) {
                    echo "<option value='".$solo->name."' ".$selected.">".$indent.$solo->name."</option>";
                }
                foreach ($getParents as $parent) {
                    echo "<optgroup label='".$parent->name."'>";
                    // How do I get the children in here?
                    echo "</optgroup>";
                }
            ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

The above outputs:

```
Entry Form
Twitter
Facebook // Bold as it is an optgroup header
```

The output should be:

```
Entry Form
Twitter
Facebook // Bold as it is an optgroup header
    Entry Form
    Page
```

So here is my question:
1) How do I get the children to appear inside the parent optgroup?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1519272

Comment: I have tried manually putting in the subquery and yielded no results either.

Answer (score 1):

You could indeed construct a suitable `NOT IN` condition in PHP and pass it to MySQL, for example like this:

```php
$parents_sql = implode(',', array_map(intval, $getParents->parent));

$getSolos = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy            
    WHERE taxonomy = 'format'           
    AND parent = 0 AND term_id NOT IN ($parents_sql)
    "));
```

(Note: The `intval` is there to make *sure* this code cannot lead to SQL injection. In your case, that shouldn't be an issue, but one can never be too sure, and in any case it's a good habit to get into.  If you were doing this with string keys, you could replace it with the appropriate string quoting function for your database.)

However, if there are a lot of parent records, it may be more efficient to use a subquery ([demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae32e/3/0)):

```sql
SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy AS t1            
WHERE taxonomy = 'format'           
AND parent = 0
AND term_id NOT IN (
    SELECT parent FROM wp_term_taxonomy         
    WHERE taxonomy = 'format'           
    AND parent > 0)
```

or a `LEFT JOIN` ([demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae32e/5/0)):

```sql
SELECT t1.term_id
FROM wp_term_taxonomy AS t1            
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS t2
    ON t1.term_id = t2.parent
WHERE t1.taxonomy = 'format'           
  AND t1.parent = 0
  AND t2.term_id IS NULL
```