# Query records that don't specific value

Tags: sql

I have a table as shown below

| id | emailTypeId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 6 |

I need to retrieve id's which does not have emailTypeId as 8 which in this case is  3 and 4.
select distinct id from table where emailTypeId <> 8 but this will retrieve records which are not 8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL: Excluding several rows if one joined row matches a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710632/mysql-excluding-several-rows-if-one-joined-row-matches-a-condition), specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14710699/283366)

Comment: tag your database as well.

Comment: So the query would be 

select id from table where id not in (select id from table where emailTypeId = 8) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
select id 
from tablename 
group by id
having count(case when emailTypeId=8 then 1 else null end) = 0
```

Comment: You don't need the `ELSE`

Comment: @JonasMetzler true, it's just more clear code and easier to understand in my opinion and has no effect on performance or whatsoever

Comment: I don't think so at all. I would agree if you prefer for example to use `INNER JOIN` over `JOIN`. In this situation, the code will really be easier to understand, especially for beginners. But adding a useless and unnecessary `ELSE` to a `CASE` doesn't improve the code. I think it even makes the impression this would be required or it would have any effect. So it's more confusing than helping. But I don't want to start a opionated discussion, maybe that's just a kind of taste.