# "where not in (subquery)" very slow for a large table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to check whether `cust_data_card_id` exists or not in table `tbl_cust_data` , exists in table `tbl_cust_dump_data.cust_data_card_id` etc.

I wrote the following code

```sql
select * from tbl_cust_dump_data 
where tbl_cust_dump_data.cust_data_card_id NOT IN
      (select cust_data_card_id from tbl_cust_data);
```

When the query returns more than  18000 rows in `tbl_cust_data` it doesn't return any result, it only shows the loading for long time, but it is okay smaller sets of data

Comment: I've added the `mysql` tag - you should do that next time. php doesn't seem to be relevant here so I didn't add that.

Comment: Show `EXPLAIN` plan and describe indexes. Start there when looking at performance issues. Also, NOT IN can be rewritten as a LEFT JOIN and NULL-check (I try to avoid sub-selects in general) which is closer to the final RA.

Comment: Is there an index on tbl_cust_data.cust_data_card_id? Also, try not selecting * but only a the columns you really need. Out of curiousity, how long does it take to run `select cust_data_card_id from tbl_cust_data` by itself and then how long does it take to run `select DISTINCT(cust_data_card_id) from tbl_cust_data`

Comment: @MrMoose there is no any index defined in cust_data_card_id in both table, i have also tried selecting only one column. also user2246674 i have tested using the outerjoin or left join ::: as select t1.cust_data_card_id from tbl_cust_data t1
inner join tbl_cust_dump_data t2
on t1.cust_data_card_id = t2.cust_data_card_id, but not responded. only executing...

Comment: If `cust_data_card_id` columns are keys (primary or foreign), then I'd highly suggest indexing them. That is likely going to provide dramatic improvements (ie. a response rather than just executing)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_cust_dump_data t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 0 
       FROM tbl_cust_data t2
       WHERE t2.cust_data_card_id = t1.cust_data_card_id)
```

With this query you will be able to select rows from `tbl_cust_dump_data`, if `cust_data_card_id` doesn't exist in table `tbl_cust_data`.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation -- this makes the page less valuable when I close a new question with this page.  Please enhance this answer.

Comment: Before using this query i used to write not in...But it takes around 30-40 secs to execute. But with this option it executes within a sec...Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a similar question asked not long ago [>> HERE <<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901755/alternative-of-not-in-on-mysql/16902932). Make sure you have `cust_data_card_id` indexed and please post the result of

```
EXPLAIN
select * from tbl_cust_dump_data 
where tbl_cust_dump_data.cust_data_card_id NOT IN
      (select cust_data_card_id from tbl_cust_data);
```

So that we can see what can be optimized further.