# Get unjoined values in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables in Mysql

**Table 1 --**

Id       candidate_id         resume

25       100                         hjksdf.jpg

26       101                         hdd.docx

29         102                       hf.docx

30       103                      hsdfh.docx

**Table 2 --**

resumes_sent_id      client_id       candidate_id          date

1                                       43                    100               2014-03-14      03

2                                     43                    101               2014-03-15      03

I need to join these two tables where `client_id` 43 after joining I need only "unjoined" records. If I join I can get `candidate_id` which values have unique 100,101. 
But in my output I need those data records which have 102,103 it means except unique values of joining.

Based on `t2` where `client_id` is 43 there are two values 100 and 101 but I want to filter unmatched values like 102.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL "NOT IN" query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519272/mysql-not-in-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.candidate_id=table1.candidate_id
WHERE table2.candidate_id IS NULL and t2.client_id=43
```

Answer (score 1):

**You got to use `Outer join` if you want unmatched records**

```
select your column names from table1 t1 outer join table2 t2 on t1.candidate_id=t2.candidate_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join and test for null

```
select * from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.candidate_id=t2.candidate_id
where t2.candidate_id is null
```

`left join` returns all rows from the first table with `t2` values where there is a match or nulls where there is no corresponding `t2` row.  From that result you want all rows where there was no match, resulting in `t2.candidate_id` being `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Use thr following code:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table 1` t1 
    LEFT JOIN `Table 2` t2 
    ON t1.candidate_id=t2.candidate_id 
    WHERE t2.candidate_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help....

IF you use not equal sign in your query then you get a result of 6 rows

```
SELECT     * FROM  TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.CLIENT_ID= 43 AND  T1.CANDIDATE_ID  T2.CANDIDATE_ID
```

BUT it includes 2 rows having 100,101 due to join

....IF YOU manually wanted to remove 100,101 id from result then got for this query..

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.CLIENT_ID= 43 AND T1.CANDIDATE_ID  T2.CANDIDATE_ID AND T1.candidate_id NOT IN(101,100)
```

Thanks