# Join on 3 tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables in MySQL 5.5 :

**product**

```
id_product int primary
product_name varchar
creation_id int (index)
```

**product_life**

```
id_product_life int primary
product_event_name varchar
product_id int (index)
creation_id int (index)
```

**date_created**

```
id_creation int primary
date_creation datetime
```

- "creation_id" from product and product_life tables are foreign keys (without constraint) for primary key id_creation of date_created table
- "product_id" from product_life table is foreign key (without constraint) for primary key id_product of product table

I need to retrieve the number of products created on a specific day (`date_creation >= '2014-08-01 00:00:00' AND date_creation <= '2014-08-01 23:59:59'`) but these products must have no records in `product_life` table having a `date_creation >= '2014-08-10 00:00:00'`

I tried with an INNER JOIN on the 3 tables but it doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to try left outer join with null clause: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519272/mysql-not-in-query

Comment: Show what you tried. [Give query, data & DDL.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM product 
INNER JOIN date_created 
        ON date_created.id_creation = product.id_creation 
WHERE (date_creation >= '2014-08-01 00:00:00' AND date_creation <= '2014-08-01 23:59:59') 
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM product_life 
       INNER JOIN date_created 
               ON date_created.id_creation = product.id_creation 
       WHERE product_id = product.id_product 
         AND date_creation >= '2014-08-10 00:00:00') = 0
```

Comment: Reasonable answer, although I think  `NOT EXISTS (SELECT * ...)` is generally preferable over `(SELECT COUNT(*) ...) = 0`.