# Get of all dates in calendar that are not in the List

Tags: mysql, outsystems

I have a list of date and I want them to be enabled in the calendarwidget of my application. The calendar widgets allows me to give only the list of dates that needs to disabled.

[image]

The issue is in the widget I am using I can give only the list of DisabledDates. I have converted the above dates in to the format 2015-3-6,2015-3-8,2015-3-7,2015-5-4,2015-5-7,2015-5-12,2015-6-16,2015-7-2,2015-10-19

But I need to get the rest of the dates in the calendar in the above format. I am not sure how do I get. Any leads is highly appreciated.

Comment: Look up how NOT IN works.  You can just provide a list of dates that you want, and get back those not on that list.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options.

Option 1: Use MySQLs 'Not In' function.

> [MySQL "NOT IN" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519272/mysql-not-in-query)

Option 2&3: Use MySQLs 'Left Join' or 'Right Join' function.

> [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Comment: Sari Rahal, How do I get the list of all dates in 2015 or 2016 to perform NOT IN Query.

Comment: You would do something like this:  SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT Date="2015" AND NOT Date="2016";            OR you can do this :  SELECT * FROM table WHERE Date != "2015" AND Date != "2016"