# SELECT record NOT IN SET of Record

Tags: mysql

`student` table

```
|----------------------|
| student_id | name    |
|------------|---------|
| 1          | Richard |
| 2          | Emily   |
| 3          | Hans    |
|------------|---------|
```

---

`lecturer` table

```
|--------------------|
| lecturer_id | name |
|-------------|------|
| 1           | John |
| 2           | Mike |
|-------------|------|
```

---

`classes` table

```
|-----------------------------------------------|
| class_id | lecturer_id | material             |
|----------|-------------|----------------------|
| 1        | 1           | Basic of algorithm   |
| 2        | 1           | Basic of programming |
| 3        | 2           | Database  Essentials |
| 4        | 2           | Basic of SQL         |
|----------|-------------|----------------------|
```

---

`attendance` table

```
|-----------------------|
| class_id | student_id |
|----------|------------|
| 1        | 1          |
| 1        | 2          |
| 1        | 3          |
| 2        | 1          |
| 2        | 2          |
| 3        | 1          |
| 3        | 2          |
| 3        | 3          |
| 4        | 1          |
| 4        | 2          |
|----------|------------|
```

---

### how to show classes records (from classes table) that not attended by Hans (student) in MySQL?

desired result :

```
|-----------------------------------------------|
| class_id | lecturer_id | material             |
|----------|-------------|----------------------|
| 2        | 1           | Basic of programming |
| 4        | 2           | Basic of SQL         |
|----------|-------------|----------------------|
```

Comment: Dup of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519272/mysql-not-in-query)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL "NOT IN" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519272/mysql-not-in-query)

Comment: i need specific result from specific parameter (Hans only), `WHERE student_id = 3`

Answer (score 1):

One approach uses `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.class_id, c.lecturer_id, c.material
FROM classes c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM attendance a
                  INNER JOIN student s
                      ON a.student_id = s.student_id
                  WHERE a.class_id = c.class_id AND
                        s.name = 'Hans');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `joins` -

```
select c.class_id
from attendance a inner join student s on (a.student_id=s.student_id and s.student_id='Hans')
right outer join classes c on (a.class_id=c.class_id)
where a.class_id is null
```

Comment: Note that nobody really uses RIGHT JOIN

Comment: @Strawberry I have never met anyone named "Nobody."  Are you really sure that anyone uses right joins?