# "How to get all ip_id of TABLE B Not present in Table A"

Tags: mysql, sql

```
TABLE A
===========
e_id    rid

160972  906913

160972  906915

160973  906924

160973  2258655

160973  2258656

160973  2258657

160973  2258658

TABLE B
==========
nid     ip_id

160972  906916

160973  2258657
```

How do i get all the ip_id of table B not present in table A in mysql ?
Get the nid of table B whose ip_id is not present in table A.

```
Expected Result
---------------
nid     ip_id

160972   NULL
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519272/mysql-not-in-query

Comment: Please add expected result set. Since it's confusing a bit.

Comment: Added the expected result

Comment: How come result of  `ip_id` would be `NULL`?

Comment: As that id will not be there in table A

Comment: I don't understand what such wilfully complex examples achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Using [NOT IN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx)

> The **IN**  operator allows you to determine if a specified value matches
>   any value in a set of values or returned by a subquery.

```
SELECT nid, id_id FROM TABLE_B WHERE ip_id NOT IN (SELECT rid FROM TABLE_A)
```